# Google Sheets show rows with multiple matching cells

Tags: google-sheets, cells

I'm needing a formula that gives me the value of the "I" cell if other cells in the row match specific values.

For instance, based on the image I've linked below, if I looked for the results of rows where B=5, C=2, D=2, E=1, and H=F, it would give me the I cell values for rows 12 and 15 (3.03 and 3.63).

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=QUERY(A:I,"SELECT I WHERE B=5 and C=2 and D=2 and E=1 and H='F'")
```

Untested as I can't be bothered to key in what you did not bother to provide as text.

Comment: Totally worked, you rock. Sorry about not providing text. I'm new to stackoverflow, and spreadsheets, and life in general :)